# ASP.Net DateTime with CultureInfo

Tags: c#, datetime, globalization, cultureinfo

One general question:

Does the DateTime object stores the CultureInfo with it, or you need to use the Formatter to format the DateTime according to current culture ?

I have a class property that retuns a DateTime. Within that property I am setting the DateTime object with current culture information using CultureInfo object. Below is the code for class property I am using:

```
public DateTime PrintedQuoteDate { 
    get {
        DateTime printQuoteDate = DateTime.Today;
        // cInfo = CultureInfo object                             

        return Convert.ToDateTime(printQuoteDate , cInfo);

    }
}
```

So my question is when I will use the above property in my code, will it have the corrosponding culture information that I am setting in its get method, or I will have to use the same CONVERT code for formatting date time. The restriction here is that the Property should return only DateTime type.

Any idea, suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` does not store any Culture what so ever. In fact it does not even hold a reference to a TimeZone, all it knows is whether it is a UTC `DateTime` or not. This is handled by an internal enum.

You need to specify a format provider (every culture in itself is a format provider) when using the ToString method of a `DateTime`, otherwise it will use the culture (really the culture and not the UI Culture) of the current thread.

You can get a predifined culture by using the ISO country/locale codes like this:

```
var us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var british = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
var danish = new CultureInfo("da");
```

As you can see for danish it is enough to specify the language since there are no other locales (to my knowledge).

Comment: side note: "en" or "fr" are working even if you don't provide Region info, there's some kind of fallback mecanism.

Comment: true, but they are missing crucial information when formatting DateTimes, like the appropriate date format: US is MM/DD/YY compared to UK being DD/MM/YY, **I strongly advise against using the fall backs when formatting dates**, all you get is the translated day names and abbreviations, if you don't display day names the generic culture info in fact does nothing for you.

Comment: I was curious if that can be stored along with date. Anyways, thanks for the reply.